# IIF function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am debugging some VBA code and I have an IIF function which I don't understand what is doing. It's `IIF(constant And i, "TRUE", "FALSE")`, where I gets values from `0` to `n`.

I know that this function is equivalent to `IF` in Excel. But in this case what is the condition? What does the expression number and number means? I run this sample:

```
Sub Sample()    
    For i = 0 To 20  
        Cells(i + 1, 1) = i
        Cells(i + 1, 2) = 4 And i
    Next i     
End Sub
```

And I get the values below:

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/iif-function?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1012957);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression `4 And i` will do an arithmetic AND-operation. Example:

```
     6:  0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
     4:  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
Result:  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0

    11:  0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1
     4:  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
Result:  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

So 6 AND 4 is 4 while 11 AND 4 is 0.
Now 0 is seen as `False` and everything not 0 is seen as `True`. Used in an IIF-statement, all numbers that have the 3rd bit (counting from right) set will execute the `True`-part of the IIF, all others the `False`.

Comment: Please, try explaining on this mechanism the result of `5 And i` (instead of `4 And i`)... The arithmetic operation is not enough, I think. The result of each bit comparing **should be a binary representation which finally is converted to decimal**... In case of `4 And i`, the `4` binary representation having the last two digits as `0`, some more ways of interpreting may look as explaining the result...

Comment: @FaneDuru: I don't understand your comment. `5 And 1` gives 1 (first bit set for both value). `5 And 2` gives 0 (no common bit). `5 And 3` gives 1. `5 And 4` gives 4 (3rd bit set). `5 And 5` gives 5 and so on.. There is no conversion taking place, this is how arithmetic with boolean operators works.

Comment: I mean that: `5 And 1` gives `0001`, converted (**to decimal**) = 1, `5 And 2` gives `0000` = 0, `5 And 4` gives `0100` = 4, `5 And 5` gives `0101` = 5, `5 And 6` gives `0100` = 4, `5 And 7` gives `0101` = 5 and so on. Microsoft definition for **And Bitwise Operator** can be seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/operators-and-expressions/logical-and-bitwise-operators)...

Comment: I don't get it.  There is no conversion. `0101` is not a string or number, it's just showing the bits, and the bit pattern `0101` is how a 5 is stored.

Comment: Exactly! `0101` is the result in **binary form**, obtained/returned by the bitwise operation.  And its `Decimal` conversion is returned in cell as `5`.  This looks to be the mechanism of `And` `Bitwise Operator` return, according to Microsoft definition... Explained in the above link.

Comment: Your link points to .Net. In VBA, it results in either an Int or a Long. `VarType(4 And 5)` gives `vbInt`, and `VarType(123456 And 5)` gives `vbLong`. But once again: There is no conversion involved, it's exactly the same as doing  `4 + 5` or `10 * 20`.

Comment: The link was meant to clarify `Bitwise Operations`, their mechanism and result being the same in VBA. It is also stated that **The result is treated as decimal**. Before of that, the article clearly explains what 'And' operator does in such a case and how the result is obtained/built (in binary form).  Only due to that conversion, `VarType` returns the `decimal` type. Now, **why** `6 AND 4`, from your answer is `4`? Not because the decimal conversion of `0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0` is `4`?

Comment: I am completley aware about bitwise operations, that's the basic for all arithmetic operations in any computer. VBA will for sure not convert anything into datatype decimal. My answer to "Why  6 AND 4 = 4" is **not** because the *decimal conversion of 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 is 4*. It's because 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 **is** 4. Of course not only 8 bits, but 16, or, more likely, 32 bits. If you make a memory dump of a memory address having a 4, you will see exactly those bits. ANDing and ORing 2 values is the most basic thing you can do on a computer.

Comment: Note that decimals are more or less not existent in VBA. And in the linked article, they don't talk about converting, they write "*The result is treated as decimal*". I just will end this discussion, but I still don't get the point of you original comment.

Comment: I agree that  ending the discussion is a good option. But before that I will like to know your opinion about the functions `BIN2DEC` and `DEC2BIN` necessity/utility in VBA. Of course, you may choose to not have any opinion about the issue...

Comment: BIN2DEC interprets a numbers or string that contains only 1 and 0 digits and calculate the decimal value out of it. Has absolute nothing to do with out discussion.

Answer (score 5):

Your `And` operator does a bit wise comparison:

```
result = expression1 And expression2
```

When applied to numeric values, the `And` operator performs a bitwise comparison of identically positioned bits in two numeric expressions and sets the corresponding bit in result according to the following table.

| If bit in expression1 is | And bit in expression2 is | The bit in result is |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |

Since the logical and bitwise operators have a lower precedence than other arithmetic and relational operators, any bitwise operations should be enclosed in parentheses to ensure accurate results.

---

So converting the `4` into binary it results in `100`. I have done that in the 3ʳᵈ column below, where I converted all numbers of the 1ˢᵗ column to binaries. The other 2 columns are just filled up with zeros for better visibility:

[image]

So watching the table above you only get a `1` as result if both bits in the same position are a `1` otherwise you get a `0`. That means you always get a `4` as result if `4 and i` has a `1` in the 3ʳᵈ bit from the right due to the bitwise comparison (see the red bits).

Comment: Nice... Al the theoretical basis is correct, but I think it should be clearer to state that the comparison result (based on the correct way you explained) will return a binary representation, which will be converted to decimal, as result. In order to better see the difference, you should try interpreting the result of `5 And i` representation (instead of `4 And i`, from the OP code example)... The specific case of `4` (followed only by `0`) gives the chance to consider only the third digit (from right to left) being relevant. All the comparisons for such a case will be `0`.

Comment: @FaneDuru well you are right, I just put the focus on the special case of the question here. Didn't want to write a whole compendium and therfore left some room for further research of the readers ;)